# Get thumbprint of a certificate

Tags: powershell, certificate

I want to store the thumbprint of a certificate in a variable like this:

```
$thumbprint = 0F273F77B77E8F60A8B5B7AACD032FFECEF4776D
```

But my command output is:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match "XXXXX"}

Thumbprint                                Subject 
----------                                ------- 
0F273F77B77E8F60A8B5B7AACD032FFECEF4776D  CN=XXXXXXX, OU=YYYYYYY
```

I need to remove everything but the thumbprint of that output

Any idea?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

All you have to do is wrap the command in parentheses, and then use dot-notation to access the `Thumbprint` property.

Try this out:

```
$Thumbprint = (Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match "XXXXXXX"}).Thumbprint;
Write-Host -Object "My thumbprint is: $Thumbprint";
```

If you get multiple certificates back from your command, then you'll have to concatenate the thumbprints into a single string, perhaps by using the `-join` PowerShell operator.

```
$Thumbprint = (Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match "XXXXXXX"}).Thumbprint -join ';';
Write-Host -Object "My thumbprints are: $Thumbprint";
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Select-Object` to get only the `Thumbprint`-property:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | 
    Where-Object {$_.Subject -match "XXXXXXX"} | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Thumbprint
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match "XXXXXXX"}
```

This one will never work cause you are using `$_.subject` you shall use `$_.thumbprint`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My |  Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -match "0F273F77B77E8F60A8B5B7AACD032FFECEF4776D"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once your variable $Thumbprint is populated after running this command
--> `$Thumbprint = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match "XXXXXXX"}`

You can access the thumbprint by using the dot-notation after your variable $Thumbprint like this
--> `$Thumbprint.Thumbprint`

This way you can also access the Subject of the certificate
--> `$Thumbprint.Subject`

Renaming the variable would make more sense in this case. :)